# Ubuntu 19.10 Network Manager not working with 5GHz

Tags: wireless, network-manager, 19.10, realtek

i have Realtek 8821ce adapter, that's support 5GHz, however after installing drivers i can only connect to 2.4G WiFi, i tested it both using my dual band router and sharing mobile phone wifi - the same result.

I can see the network and trying to connect, but unsuccessfully, it keeps asking to reenter password.

I've seen some suggestions to change channel from auto to some fixed, but in my case it doesn't work

**UPDATE:**
seems that the problem is somehow related to builtin network manager, i tried WICD network manager and was able to connect to my 5GHz network

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, the radio frequency of 5GHz is really short and it goes like a laser. Are you in the range? Is there nothing to obstacle receiving/sending? A thick paper wall, some cloth or a wooden door shorten range, it is normally less than 100 ft/ 50 meters

Comment: Hi, no, that's no the case, previously on the same notebook in the same place i used Elementary OS and it was working on both 5GHz and 2.4Ghz without any problem. Also as i said, i tried sharing 5G wifi using mobile phone and it's even didn't see the network in that case

Comment: Noticed another matter, the US and Japan (or in other countries I am not sure) have been regulating the 5Ghz range for the public use since then the product may disabled 5GHz function in these restricted area. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Channels_and_frequencies

Comment: 20.04.1 LTS is available - consider moving to that and then reposting / editing if still an issue

Answer (score -1):

You can update your system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding ppa:vicamo/ppa-1861278 to your system's Software Sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vicamo/ppa-1861278

sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: The ppa:vicamo/ppa-1861278 PPA does no5t support Ubuntu 19.10.